# How can you insert at the end of an existing string filed a datafield with string type in MySQL kinda like CONCAT

Tags: mysql, string, concatenation

Hello i have into my database (mysql) two string fields and i would like to put the second string into the end of the first string kinda like concat works. example

```
UPDATE cscart_product_descriptions
SET meta_keywords=CONCAT(meta_keywords, product_id)
```

My problem is that i dont know how to make the Concat function to understand that product_id is a field in my database and not a fixed string like 'product_id'

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since you don't put it in quotes, it's treated as a column name. What's the problem?

Comment: ty Barmar my problem solved ,i found out that this wasnt my concat() problem but a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SET meta_keywords=CONCAT(meta_keywords, product_id)
```

will concat two columns

example:

```
   meta_keywords, product_id
      dddd      , 2
```

will result

```
     dddd2
```

and

```
  SET meta_keywords=CONCAT(meta_keywords, 'product_id')
```

will result

```
   ddddproduct_id
```

Comment: i found out that my problem was in my inner join tryed to put a where in the end instead do it like UPDATE  cscart_products INNER JOIN cscart_product_descriptions
on cscart_products.product_id=cscart_product_descriptions.product_id
SET meta_keywords=CONCAT(meta_keywords, cscart_products.product_code) now it works :)